# XACT_ABORT behaving inconsistently with sp_recompile in the batch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two similar TSQL scripts where I  have SET XACT_ABORT ON.  I expect **_test** table to NOT EXIST after script execution as I am intentionally using a statement wrapped in a transaction that will raise an error.

The first script correctly rolls back the creation of _test table.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE TABLE dbo._test(ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL)
EXEC sp_does_not_exist --raises error!
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT;
```

However, the second script does not roll back the creation of _test and the table exists after the script execution:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE TABLE dbo._test(ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL)
EXEC sp_recompile sp_does_not_exist; --raises error!
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT;
```

Why does the second script not remove the _test table after execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned your SQL Server version, but since the only difference in your script is `sp_recompile`, that seems like a good place to look. In 2008R2 it has the following logic:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- CHECK VALIDITY OF OBJECT NAME --
--  (1) Must exist in current database
--  (2) Must be a table or an executable object
select @objid = object_id(@objname, 'local')

    if @objid is null OR
        (ObjectProperty(@objid, 'IsTable') = 0 AND
         ObjectProperty(@objid, 'IsExecuted') = 0)
    begin
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        raiserror(15165,-1,-1 ,@objname)
        return @@error
    end
```

So `sp_recompile` checks for the existence of the object *before* it tries to access it directly, and if it isn't found it raises an error with severity -1. The documentation for `RAISERROR` [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that a severity level less than zero is interpreted as zero, and the documentation for severity levels [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that no system error is raised on severity zero.

Indeed, adding the `RAISERROR` from `sp_recompile` into your script shows that it doesn't affect `@@TRANCOUNT`:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE TABLE dbo._test(ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL)
select @@trancount as 'before raiserror'    
raiserror(15165,-1,-1 ,'sp_does_not_exist')
select @@trancount as 'after raiserror' 

GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT;
```

`@@TRANCOUNT` is 1 before and after the error is raised, so there is nothing to trigger a rollback. But if you do this, the second `SELECT` is never executed, because the error has been raised 'directly' by the database engine:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE TABLE dbo._test(ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL)
select @@trancount as 'before raiserror'    
exec sp_does_not_exist
select @@trancount as 'after raiserror' 

GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: It shows up as red in SSMS indicating a "proper" error.  I assume it uses the severity 16 `select * from sys.messages where message_id = 15165`. Errors raised by `RAISERROR` yourself [do **not** generally cause `XACT_ABORT` roll backs](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#XACT_ABORT). Not sure if any different in a system stored procedure.